# helm rollback and upgrade - order of hook execution

Tags: hook, kubernetes-helm, rollback

We have a helm that has the following hooks-
a) pre upgrade
b) pre rollback
c) post delete
d) post rollback
What is the order of the execution of these hooks with install and unistall job?

When upgrade is performed, is it pre-upgrade,install job then post-upgrade?
For rollback - is it pre-rollback,uninstall job, install job and then post-rollback or 
pre-rollback,uninstall job ( post delete hook),post-rollback and then install job?

Answer (score 1):

What is your helm version? A slight difference from helmv2 in helmv3 is that the CRD hooks are removed and there is no garbage collection for hooks. There's a detailed doc for the execution of hooks lifecycle and also if you want to put weights on hook to define a particular order of execution in helm subcharts.

Please check the lifecycle section for details on hooks. I can explain further if the doc isn't clear enough.This doc is for helmv3
https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/